# How to do cumulative mean and count in a easy way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
data = {'call_put':['C', 'C', 'P','C', 'P'],'price':[10,20,30,40,50], 'qty':[11,12,11,14,9]}
df['amt']=df.price*df.qty
df=pd.DataFrame(data)


call_put    price   qty amt
0   C   10  11  110
1   C   20  12  240
2   P   30  11  330
3   C   40  14  560
4   P   50  9   450
```

I want output something like following based on call_put value is 'C' or 'P' count, median and calculation as follows

```
call_put price  qty amt      cummcount    cummmedian               cummsum           

C   10  11  110      1            110                       110
C   20  12  240      2            175    ((110+240)/2 )     350  
P   30  11  330      1            330                       680
C   40  14  560      3            303.33 (110+240+560)/3   1240
P   50  9   450      2            390 ((330+450)/2)        1690
```

Can it be done in some easy way without creating additional dataframes and functions?

Answer (score 1):

create a grouped element named `g` and use `df.assign` to assign values:

```
g=df.groupby('call_put')
final=df.assign(cum_count=g.cumcount().add(1),
   cummedian=g['amt'].expanding().mean().reset_index(drop=True), cum_sum=df.amt.cumsum())
```

---

```
  call_put  price  qty  amt  cum_count   cummedian  cum_sum
0        C     10   11  110          1  110.000000      110
1        C     20   12  240          2  175.000000      350
2        P     30   11  330          1  303.333333      680
3        C     40   14  560          3  330.000000     1240
4        P     50    9  450          2  390.000000     1690
```

Note: for `P` , the `cummedian` should be 390 since (330+450)/2 = 390

For `cum_count` look at [`df.groupby.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
for `cummedian` check how [`expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) works , 
for cumsum check [`df.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should work

```
df['cumcount']=df.groupby('call_put').cumcount()

df['cummidean']=df.groupby('call_put')['amt'].cumsum()

df['cumsum']=df.groupby('call_put').cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks following solution is fine

g=df.groupby('call_put')
final=df.assign(cum_count=g.cumcount().add(1),
   cummedian=g['amt'].expanding().mean().reset_index(drop=True), cum_sum=df.amt.cumsum())

1. if I run following without drop=True

g['amt'].expanding().mean().reset_index()

why output is showing level_1

```
call_put    level_1 amt
```

0   C   0   110.000000
1   C   1   175.000000
2   C   3   303.333333
3   P   2   330.000000
4   P   4   390.000000

g['amt'].expanding().mean().reset_index(drop=True)

0    110.000000
1    175.000000
2    303.333333
3    330.000000
4    390.000000
Name: amt, dtype: float64

Can you pl explain in more detail ?

2. How do you add one more condition in groupby clause

g=df.groupby('call_put', 'price' < 50)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'